# Trying to convert factor values. Getting NA's or incorrect values instead

Tags: r

I have a dataframe "baseball" with batting stats for some college baseball players. I'm trying to convert the players' year in college (Fr., So., Jr., Sr.) to a numeric value (1, 2, 3, 4). I've tried a couple different methods and I can't seem to get it right.

This is what I'm starting with:

```
    > baseball$Yr.
    [1] Jr. Jr. So. Jr. Jr. Fr. Jr. Jr. So. Jr.
    [11] Sr. Jr. Sr. So. Jr. Sr. So. Jr.
    Levels: Fr. Jr. So. Sr.
```

1) First, I tried this:

```
    > modBaseball = baseball
    > levels(modBaseball$Yr.)
      [1] "Fr." "Jr." "So." "Sr."
    > levels(modBaseball$Yr.) = c(1,3,2,4)
    > modBaseball$Yr.
      [1] 3 3 2 3 3 1 3 3 2 3 4 3 4 2 3 4 2 3
      Levels: 1 3 2 4
    > class(modBaseball$Yr.)
      [1] "factor"
```

"modBaseball$Yr." is correct, except that the class is still a factor, so I did this:

```
    > class(modBaseball$Yr.) = "integer"
    > class(modBaseball$Yr.)
      [1] "integer"
    > modBaseball$Yr.
      [1] 2 2 3 2 2 1 2 2 3 2 4 2 4 3 2 4 3 2
      attr(,"levels")
      [1] "1" "3" "2" "4"
```

Now, the values have changed! I figure it's because of the way the factors are stored and the order in which I input the new levels.

2) So, I tried it again, but this time I set the levels to `c(1,2,3,4)`. As expected, the values were incorrectly assigned.

3) Then, I did some research and tried manually creating the factors first:

```
    > modBaseball = baseball
    > f = factor(modBaseball$Yr., levels=c(1,2,3,4), ordered=TRUE)
    > f
      [1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
      [9] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
      [17] <NA> <NA>
      Levels: 1 < 2 < 3 < 4
```

Now the data is all NA's! What am I doing wrong? I expected the factor function to assign the levels 1,2,3,4 to the ordered list of values, but apparently, that's not how it works.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using `as.numeric()` anywhere?

Comment: The levels of a factor will always be character values.

Comment: Technically they *are* integer values under the hood. That is the point of a factor. I suggest some reading... try `?factor`!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could correctly level the factor in the first place.

```
modBaseball$Yr. = factor(modBaseball$Yr., levels=c("Fr.","So.", "Jr.", "Sr.")).
```

Then a regular as.numeric() should be just fine

```
as.numeric(modBaseball$Yr.)
```

Plus, when you specify the order of the levels explicitly, the order of the output for most plotting and summary functions will automatically be in that order as well.

Comment: This did the trick! Since the levels were added automatically, I didn't think manually entering them would make a difference. I suppose as long as the level names that you manually enter match up exactly with the values you pass to the function, it re-assigns the level numbers correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Should do the trick:

```
c(1,3,2,4)[baseball$Yr]
```

If you learn more about how factors work in R, you'll see that factors are really just integers with "character" labels. So while you see `"Fr.", "Sr."`, R looks at it as `1, 4`, and just knows that you want 1 to correspond to Fr., etc.

R naturally orders things alphabetically, which is why it has the order `Fr., Jr., So., Sr.`. So Jr. was actually corresponding to 2, and So. to 3. Sr and Fr were coincidentally in the right place.

The above line of code says take the vector `1, 3, 2, 4`. Since R sees `Jr.` as 2, every time it sees `Jr.` (actually seeing 2), it will take the 2nd element of that vector, which is 3.

Comment: Sure, it sounded like his goal was just to get numeric values.

Comment: This solution worked as well. I'm not exactly sure WHY, though. I need to look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @user3712613 added explanation.